# Bootstrap 4. CSS minification produces wrong results

Tags: gulp, laravel-elixir, bootstrap-4, gulp-clean-css, gulp-minify-css

I have installed Bootstrap 4.0-alpha with Bower and now I have a dist directory with precompiled bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css. In development environment I try to use not compressed version, but minified version within deployment. I use Laravel Elixir to run my tasks. After compressing, some bootstrap styles has been changed. For example, h1 tag has got "margin-top: 0.67em" (it has happened, because "margin-top: 0px" has got lower priority). Of course, I can simply use precompressed file from dist directory which is complitely fine. But if it's an issue of my minifier, I am afraid that it will lead to the wrong results in further development.So my question is why it's happening?

Comment: FYI gulp-minify-css has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) in favor of [gulp-clean-css](https://github.com/scniro/gulp-clean-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bootstrap build chain uses `grunt-contrib-css` which uses `clean-css` (version 3.4.6)

In the Gruntfile.js the option `noAdvanced: true` had been set. As far as i do understande this is not an option for `grunt-contrib-css` neither `clean-css`. Instead `advanced: false` should be set:

```
cssmin: {
  options: {
    // TODO: disable `zeroUnits` optimization once clean-css 3.2 is released
    //    and then simplify the fix for https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14837 accordingly
    compatibility: 'ie9',
    keepSpecialComments: '*',
    sourceMap: true,
    advanced: false
  },
```

Comment: fixed: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/bd5d25da44015d6804c7abf2c1ede35a6071f8d0